# Springboot 2.2 and graphql RawClassRequiredForGraphQLMappingException: Entity cannot be mapped to a GraphQL type

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, graphql-java

I'm working on a test project using Cassandra, GraphQL and Spring Boot 2.2.0.M1. I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Below is my table in cassandra after I execute `DESC TABLE product`

```
CREATE TABLE jerseys237.product (
 prod_id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
 available float,
 description text,
 discount float,
 league text,
 picture text,
 price float,
 team_country text,
 team_crest text,
 team_name text,
 team_region text,
 title text
)...
```

My `product.grapqls` file:

```
type Product { 
  prod_id: ID!
  available: Float
  description: String
  discount: Float
  league: String
  picture: String
  price: Float
  team_country: String
  team_crest: String
  team_name: String
  team_region: String
  title: String
}

type Query {  
 findAllProducts: [Product]  
 findProductByPrice(price: Float!): Product
 findProductByTitle(title: String!): Product
 countProducts: Long 
}  

type Mutation { 
 deleteProduct(prod_id: String!) : Boolean 
}

schema {
 query: Query
 mutation: Mutation   
}
```

Also there is a `@Component public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver` class that seems not to have any issue. And finally I have the `Product Class`:

```
  @Data
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @Table 
  public class Product {

@PrimaryKey
private String prod_id;
private Float available;
private String description;
private Float discount;
private String league; 
private String picture; //  or  private Byte[] picture; ??
private Float price;
private String team_country;
private String team_crest;  
private String team_name;
private String team_region;
private String title;

public Product(Float available, String description, Float discount, String league, String picture, Float price, String team_country, String team_crest, String team_name, String team_region, String title) {
    this.prod_id = UUIDs.timeBased().toString(); // automatically generate timeuuid
    this.available = available;
    this.description = description;
    this.discount = discount;
    this.league = league;
    this.picture = picture;
    this.price = price;
    this.team_country = team_country;
    this.team_crest = team_crest;
    this.team_name = team_name;
    this.team_region = team_region;
    this.title = title;
  }  
 }
```

As you can see certain columns in the Cassandra keyspace (e.g. `team_crest`) ought to be of type `blob` but I couldn't map it to a Java type successfully (but that's another question). So here is the problem, after changing spring boot versions and even dependency versions, each time I run the app in my netbeans I get this error:

`com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.TypeClassMatcher$RawClassRequiredForGraphQLMappingException: Type java.util.List<com.creatixxx.jersey.entities.Product> cannot be mapped to a GraphQL type!  Since GraphQL-Java deals with erased types at runtime, only non-parameterized classes can represent a GraphQL type.  This allows for reverse-lookup by java class in interfaces and union types`

How can I solve this error and get my app to work?

Comment: You've probably followed my obsolete tutorial since you have very very old versions of everything. I highly recommend you try using graphql-java directly by following [this](https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/) tutorial. You might also wish to try my project called GraphQL SPQR, if you're interested in code-first approach.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually used the latest of everything but still got the exact same error so i downgraded as per this other tutorial https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/building-a-graphql-server-with-spring-boot

Comment: Here's the version of your tutorial i followed: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql

Comment: The exact error you're getting is coming from graphql-java-tools, which now lives under `com.graphql-java-kickstart` groupId and is at version 5.7.2. The exception message is bogus... graphql-java has no issues with lists or generics. That's why I suggest using graphql-java directly. The official tutorial should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you very much @kaqqao I really appreciate